dolibarr cronjob php file error( TypeError: Cronjob::create(): )

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cronjob::create(): Argument #1 ($user) must be of type User, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\dolibarr\core\modules\DolibarrModules.class.php on line 1695 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\dolibarr\cron\class\cronjob.class.php:214 Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dolibarr\core\modules\DolibarrModules.class.php(1695): Cronjob->create(NULL)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\dolibarr\core\modules\DolibarrModules.class.php(564): DolibarrModules->insert_cronjobs()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\dolibarr\core\modules\modAgenda.class.php(615): DolibarrModules->_init(Array, '')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\dolibarr\core\lib\admin.lib.php(1228): modAgenda->init()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\dolibarr\install\step5.php(360): activateModule('modAgenda', 1)
#5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dolibarr\cron\class\cronjob.class.php on line 214

i can change cronjob file C:\xampp\htdocs\dolibarr\core\modules\DolibarrModules.class.php to
gobal $user; 

and then : C:\xampp\htdocs\dolibarr\core\modules\DolibarrModules.class.php
DolibarrModules->insert_cronjobs()

will added
but Am facing error .

I'd suggest contacting the dev of the plugin, there might be a step you're missing, or it might be a bug.

i think its dev bug
